# Getting "User [dr.who] is not authorized to view the logs for application <AppID>" while running a YARN application

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, apache-twill

I'm running a custom Yarn Application using Apache Twill in HDP 2.5 cluster, but I'm not able to see my own container logs (syslog, stderr and stdout) when I go to my container web page:
[image]

Also the login changes from my kerberos to "dr.who" when I navigate to this page.
But I can see the logs of map-reduce jobs. Hadoop version is 2.7.3 and the cluster is yarn acl enabled.

Comment: My 2 cents: the cluster is kerberized, YARN is kerberized, HistoryServer is kerberized... but the **YARN User Interface** is not kerberized -- anyone can connect to the web server without any authentication; the web server connects to HistoryServer with the hard-coded dummy name `Dr.Who`; so anyone can browse the jobs *(no ACL for that)*, but no-one can open the log files *(because of ACLs)*.

Comment: Connect to the Edge Node with SSH, create a Kerberos ticket with `kinit`, then access the logs with command line `yarn logs -applicationId application_0000000_0000` -- that command line *is* kerberized because it uses low-level RPC calls. And don't forget `| more` because you will get an awful lot of content.

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter I tried that actually but when the app is live and running I get the following message after running yarn logs command:
**"can not find any log file matching the pattern: [all] for the container: ..."**, but when I kill the application, I can see all the logs. I checked that the log files are not present actually in this directory "/yarn/logs/<user>/logs/<appid>/<node_addr_container>" when the app is running, it gets created only when I kill the application. Do I need to set some Yarn log configs manually so that I can see the logs real time using this command?

Comment: _"set configs ... [to] see the logs real time"_ > You can't. Logs are collected by HistoryServer when the job AM terminates the execution. That's one of the pains of long-running streaming apps (and services) which has no good solution yet, cf. https://www.slideshare.net/HadoopSummit/running-services-on-yarn/23

Comment: Right now, if you want to "stream" logs out of a running container, you have to build your own streaming system -- e.g. start a Flume agent on the Edge Node; in your app, define a specific Log4J output for "applicative" logs, using the Flume plug-in, to stream these logs to the agent; set up the agent to flush results to a local file every N seconds.

Comment: FYI, twill will stream the application logs back to the client via a Kafka queue that it sets up.

Comment: Hi @MartinSerrano ! I know that logs will be sent back to the client but it was really very convenient to see the stderr and stdout from the container node web UI itself. I was able to do that in HDP 2.2 but no longer in HDP 2.5

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter :) you've been very helpful, I just need to know one thing that I don't really need to stream the logs out of the container, but if I'm able  to see the stdout of a container that is sufficient for me. I'm able to see the syslogs, stderrs etc for map-reduce jobs in the same cluster using the same web UI and earlier in HDP 2.2 I was able to see stdouts of Yarn application as well. 

Can I specify [ApplicationAccessType](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationAccessType.html) from any yarn config property for a yarn app?

Comment: No idea... But again, AFAIK, `stdout` is captured by the YARN container wrapper, and shipped to HistoryServer just before the container resources are released.

Answer (score 2):

i had this issue with hadoop ui. I found in [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) doc, that the *hadoop.http.staticuser.user* is set to *dr.who* by default and you need include it in the related setting file (in my issue is *core-site.xml* file).
so late but hope useful.